# Fast way to find neighbors whose distance is less than a threshold?

Tags: algorithm, graph, nearest-neighbor

What I am doing is this:

1. for a point, compute the distance to all the other point
2. get the points whose distance to current distance is less than threshold(for example 500)
3. for all point, do this same thing.

My way is totally brute-force approach, how can I improve this? (Because the brute-force way is too slow)

```
# compute distance with latitude and longitude
def space_dist(c1, c2):
    return math.sqrt((float(c1[0])-float(c2[0]))*(float(c1[0])-float(c2[0]))+(float(c1[1])-float(c2[1]))*(float(c1[1])-float(c2[1])))

def _cluster_by_dist(i, threshold=500):
    address = address_group[i]
    threshold = threshold / 27.0 / 3600.0
    ids = [i]
    for oidx, o in enumerate(address_group):
        if oidx == i:
            continue

        dist = space_dist((address[i_x], address[i_y]), (o[i_x], o[i_y]))
        if dist >= threshold:
            continue

        ids.append(oidx)
    return ids

def cluster_check():
    pool = Pool()
    cnt = 0
    t = time.time()
    for ids in pool.imap(_cluster_by_dist, range(len(address_group))):
        cnt += 1
        if cnt % 100 == 0:
            print("{}: {}".format(cnt, time.time() - t))
            t = time.time()
        if len(ids) <= 1:
            continue

        yield([address_group[i] for i in ids])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    columns = "id,key,mode,x,y,freq".split(",")
    address_group = list(load_raw_data("input_path", columns))
    i_key, i_x, i_y = columns.index("key"), columns.index("x"), columns.index("y")

    for addresses in cluster_check():
        for address in addresses:
            print(address)
        print()
```

Comment: Triangle inequality? If you've measured |ab| and |ac| there's a good chance that you already know |bc| is either smaller or greater than the threshold. Obviously you need some sort of memoization to get this to work. Also, compare the distance squared to the threshold squared, to avoid the square roots.

Comment: @m69 In fact the `space_dist` compute the distance of `latitude and longitude`(these points are real latitude longitude in earth), but I don't get it, if `dist(A, B) < threshold` and `dist(A, C) < threshold`, I cannot decide `dist(A, C) < threshold`

Comment: If |ab| + |ac| < T then |bc| < T. If |ab| - |ac| > T or |ac| - |ab| > T then |bc| > T.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree is an example of a datastructure for neighborhood search that requires only the triangle inequality. Alternatively you could use whatever your favorite tree structure is and add annotations at the nodes giving the maximum distance from the point at the node to any of its descendants. This would allow you to rule out some subtrees during neighborhood search.